# Applying common external CSS to contents of only one frame

Tags: css

I have a frame layout with  tag.One of the frame gets loaded when the links in other frames is clicked.The contents of the frame originates from several JSPs.Is there a way to apply common CSS to all the JSPs being displayed on that particular frame in the parent layout itself instead of defining CSS with link tag in each JSP pages?Also is it possible only with javasript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to embed the css to the iframe by using this javascript

```
var cssLink = document.createElement("link") 
cssLink.href = "mystyle.css"; 
cssLink .rel = "stylesheet"; 
cssLink .type = "text/css"; 
frames['myframe'].document.body.appendChild(cssLink);
```

Comment: Yes thanks.I added the script in the onload() of the frame and it works fine.